# exchange 2013 delete mails from folder

Tags: powershell, exchange, microsoft

I wish to delete some error messages from the Syncronizations\conflicts folder of a specific customer.
How can I do it using ECP or Powershell (EMS). I have administration rights

Comment: Did you read this: https://docs.microsoft.com/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/deleting-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Comment: @bjoster Yes and unfortunately it does not help me.

Comment: sadly I discovered that when I do a searchquery  -SearchQuery "from:" it works but if I do the searchquery as -SearchQuery "folderid:063C....." it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it could use `“Search-Mailbox -Identity "User" -SearchQuery 'Subject:"xxx"' -DeleteContent”` to search and delete messages with specific subject.

In my understanding, there is no build-in command that could delete items in a specific folder. If you want to delete in a specific folder, have a try such script using EWS. Here is a reference:
https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2012/07/reporting-and-clearing-syncissues.html

Comment: Unfortunately that script also did not help. I tried to change a little bit but; first I am not good at powershell scripting and secondly script is for exchange 2010 but I have Exchange2013 and I guess thats why it does not find the correct data. it says it finds folder and Item count (which is 0) of a folder which has 244 items in it.

Comment: ok here i made it work. made some changes in the script as below 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Bin\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll" 
I will try to develop it hopefully when I find time. But thanks for help.